# auto-renew subscription in-app billing google play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

This is my first time to deal with in-app billing in android, I want to know If I want to use monthly subscription to my application, is the option of auto-renew subscription in on by default, or user should do something in his/her google wallet account to allow auto-renew subscription in my app

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is recurring by default. When user buys subscription, it automatically recurs based on an interval you specify in Developer Console, and User can cancel at any time.

[The docs say](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html):

> After users have purchased subscriptions, they can view the
>   subscriptions and cancel them from the My Apps screen in the Play
>   Store app or from the app's product details page in the Play Store
>   app.

Additionally,

> Billing continues indefinitely at the interval and price specified for
>   the subscription. At each subscription renewal, Google Play charges
>   the user account automatically, then notifies the user of the charges
>   afterward by email. For monthly and annual subscriptions, billing
>   cycles will always match subscription cycles, based on the purchase
>   date.

See:

- http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html
- http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#cancellation